# UV stretch weird

Tags: modeling, uv, geometry

I can't understand how can I sort out this weird uv situation…
When using an image that is not 1:1 and trying to uv it, the texture stretches depending on the original image and not the geometry(!)
I am trying to create a baking uvs and the stretching is not allowing me to create non-stretched uvs.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your plane should have uneven scale.

Comment: Nope, it is another reason. Let me write the answer

Comment: I know it is uneven, but this is why I am asking this question - when using uneven scale image the uv get stretched, I would like to bake the uneven texture but use uvs that are unaffected by the texture rather by the geometry if it makes sense...

Answer (score 4):

You have selected an image in the shader nodes. Which is going to be active in this case.

[image]

The image has uneven scale, and Blender takes into account the aspect ratio of this image, then generating the UV.

[image]

If you add a new image with 1:1 aspect ratio, Blender will create a square UV.

[image]

Comment: Not good for me as I need to bake an uneven texture, but I guess you are right.. If I am adding an image node and make it 1:1 it unwraps okay.